# formatter argument in scale_continuous throwing errors in R 2.15

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since upgrading to R 2.15, the formatter argument seems to be throwing errors. This was an argument that I've been using everyday for 2 years, so a huge bummer.

R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)

ggplot2 version 0.9.0

```
> library(ggplot2)
> x <- 1:100
> y <- 1/x
> p <- qplot(x,y)
> p + scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent")
Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  unused argument(s) (formatter = "percent")
```

Comment: Nevermind...page 31: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf

Comment: Trim off the leading `'cloud.'` to make a useful ink.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The syntax has changed with version 0.9.0. See the transition guide here: https://github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
x <- 1:100
y <- 1/x
p <- qplot(x,y) + scale_y_continuous(labels  = percent)
```