# How to display value in a stacked bar chart by using geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display the percentage figures in the stacked bar. However, one group has a really low percentage. Two values are overlapping each other. I change to 'postion='identity'. It still wont work.....any thoughts?

```
x4.can.m <- structure(list(canopy = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0%", "1 to 84%", 
"85% +"), class = "factor"), YearQuarter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("2011-09-01", 
"2011-12-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-06-01", "2012-09-01"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.51, 0.01, 0.48, 0.52, 0.01, 0.47, 0.53, 0.01, 
    0.47, 0.57, 0.01, 0.41, 0.61, 0.01, 0.38)), .Names = c("canopy", 
"YearQuarter", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")


x4.can.bar <- ggplot(data=x4.can.m, aes(x=factor(YearQuarter), y=value,fill=canopy)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "stack",ymax=100)

x4.can.bar+scale_y_continuous(formatter='percent')+
 labs(y="Percentage",x="Year Quarter") + 
 geom_text(aes(label =paste(round(value*100,0),"%",sep="")),size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 4,position ="identity")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

one solution is to change the stack bar to a dodge one

```
x4.can.bar <- ggplot(data=x4.can.m, aes(x=factor(YearQuarter), y=value,fill=canopy)) + 
                    geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge",ymax=100) +
             geom_text(aes(label =paste(round(value*100,0),"%",sep=""),ymax=0), 
                       position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
x4.can.bar
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify reasonable values for the placement of the labels - if you do this outside the `ggplot` call, it will be far easier than trying to do so within the call.

You can do this by taking the midpoint of each stacked component.

Using `plyr` and `ddply` this is a simple as taking the cumulative sum and subtracting half the current value within each `YearQuarter`

```
library(plyr)
x4.can.m <- ddply(x4.can.m, .(YearQuarter), mutate, csum = cumsum(value)-value/2)

x4.can.bar <- ggplot(data=x4.can.m, aes(x=factor(YearQuarter), y=value,fill=canopy)) +  
 geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "stack",ymax=100)

x4.can.bar + 
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = percent) +
 labs(y="Percentage",x="Year Quarter")+
 geom_text(aes(y = csum,label =paste(round(value*100,0),"%",sep="")),
           size = 3, hjust = 1, vjust = 0)
```

Note that I am using `ggplot2_0.9.2.1`, so `formatter` is no longer a valid argument to `scale_y_continuous`, replaced with `label = percent`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146109/formatter-argument-in-scale-continuous-throwing-errors-in-r-2-15) and related links

[image]

Comment: @mnel, thanks. what's the easiest to way to upgrade to ggplot2_0.9.2.1. I am using R_2.15.1 still.....

Comment: in a new R session run `install.packages('ggplot2')`

Comment: did melt() funciton disappear in R_2.15.0.2?

Comment: No. `ggplot2` used to load `reshape2` onto the search path, the newer versions `import` `reshape2` so the functions are available for `ggplot2`. run `library(reshape2)` to load explicitly.