# geom_text on only top part of stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack, bar-chart, geom-text

I would like to have labels on only the top part of my stacked bar plot.

Here is my data frame:

```
#create data frame 
building <- c("Burj \nKhalifa", "Zifeng \nTower", "Bank of \nAmerica Tower", 
              "Burj Al Arab", "Emirates \nTower One", "New York \nTimes Tower",
              "Emirates \nTower Two", "Rose Rayhaan \nby Rotana", "The \nPinnacle", 
              "Minsheng \nBank Building")
occupiable<- c(585, 317, 235, 198, 241, 220, 213, 237, 265, 237)
nonoccupiable <- c(244, 133, 131, 124, 113, 99, 97, 96, 95, 94)
df.build <- data.frame(building, occupiable, nonoccupiable)

#melt data frame for stack bar plot
df.build2 <- melt(df.build, id.vars="building")
```

And my stacked bar plot:

```
#comparision true and percived values
ggplot(df.build2, aes(x=reorder(building, -value), y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
 #geom_text(aes(label = c("29%" "30%", "36%", "39%", "32%", "31%", "31%", "29%", "29%", "28%")), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack") +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  ggtitle("Porównanie wartości prawdziwych i odczuwalnych")
```

[image]

I would like to have labels like this in `geom_text()` in my code for plotting (height of blue bar/height of whole bar). It should be placed in the blue area. How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576139/how-to-display-value-in-a-stacked-bar-chart-by-using-geom-text) question, the top-scored answer looks very similar to your desired solution.

Comment: Ok, but I want to have only a half of labels, (only for blue bars). So if I define `percentage <- nonoccupiable/(nonoccupiable+occupiable)` and add to ggplot line `geom_text(aes(y=percentage, label = paste(round(percentage*100,0),"%",sep="")), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3)` I get error: `Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:percentage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution (I also changed the angle of the x-axis text):

```
# creating percentage variables
df.build$occ.perc <- round(df.build$occupiable / (df.build$occupiable + df.build$nonoccupiable) * 100)
df.build$nonocc.perc <- round(df.build$nonoccupiable / (df.build$occupiable + df.build$nonoccupiable) * 100)

# melt data frame for stack bar plot![enter image description here][1]
df.build2 <- cbind(
  melt(df.build, id = c("building"), measure = c(2:3)),
  melt(df.build, id = c("building"), measure = c(4:5), value.name = "perc")
)
df.build2 <- df.build2[,-c(4,5)]
df.build2$perc <- ifelse(df.build2$variable=="occupiable", df.build2$perc==NA, df.build2$perc)

# creating the plot
ggplot(df.build2, aes(x=reorder(building, -value), y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  geom_text(aes(label = perc), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, position = "stack") +
  theme(legend.position="top", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust=0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Porównanie wartości prawdziwych i odczuwalnych")
```

the result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 problems, you are missing a comma betweeen the first two elements of your label vector; and, your label vector is too short. Even though you have what looks like 10 bars, you infact have 20 (since they are stacked). To get around this precede your labels by 10 blank character strings:

```
geom_text(
 aes(label = c(rep("",10),
 "29%", "30%", "36%", "39%", "32%", "31%", "31%", "29%", "29%", "28%")),
size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

Which gives:

[image: stacked barchart]